# After decoding image sent from Android the image size was increased in php

Tags: php, android, upload

I am sending the image from android as base64 string to PHP. After decoding the image in PHP the size of image is increased. For example the size of the image is 60kb then after decoding in PHP it becomes 200kb. How to maintain the same file size even in PHP.

```
$rimage=$_POST['profile'];
$decodedImage = base64_decode($rimage);
```

Am directly store the $decodeImage into the folder. I've tried using the imagecreatefromstring($decodedImage) but this doesn't solve the problem.

Android code for converting image into base64 string

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

After this i am sending it to the PHP server using Volley.

Problem Solved by using the below code instead of the above which recompress the image again.

```
  InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);//You can get aninputStream using any IO API
  byte[] bytes;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
  int bytesRead;
  ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  try {
   while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
   output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
  }
  } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  bytes = output.toByteArray();
 String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Show your Java code please.

Comment: does the image work?  That is the real question.

Comment: Yes. You use BitmapFactory to send an image. Thats the problem. Are you sending a file? Pretty unclear where your image comes from. And where you determine its size.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix - Image conversion code is attached and it is working.

Comment: well its not uncommon for files to be different from say FAT to NTFS for example.  Or from raided to non-raided, but that's quite a different size, and I am no expert in that regard.  If the image shows up like it should then \o/

Comment: thanks all for your comments

Comment: `Android code for converting image into base64 string`. No you convert a Bitmap to a JPG. And it is unclear which size you mean and where the Bitmap comes from.

Comment: For sure going from bmp to jpg will be different size, the whole point of jpg is lossy compression after all.